# Select paragraph text in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I've seen the typical `('myContainer').select();` in Jquery.  However, is there a way to select text within a `.container` div with Angular?  I cannot find anything in the API reference and every search references the select element.

Answer (score 0):

Angular does have `.text()` in its jQLite[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

You'd call it in a directive like:

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.directive('someDirective', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'template.html',
    transclude: true,
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.content = {
        changeText: function() {
          button = element.find('button');
          button.text('Nice new button')
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
)
```